# How to keep my categories visible on the plot after Kmeans achieved, in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, k-means

How to I keep I visualise my factor variable without any number when clustering it's done? I want a more elegant data visualisation. Not as in this picture:

[image]

Yet, the one I retrieved from my kmean clustering does seem to be as nice as in the - https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering. As you can see, the author manages nicely to plot the cities as factor, where the names are visible.

Here is the data I have:

```
data_piv <- structure(list(Comorbidities = structure(1:9, .Label = c("asthma", 
    "diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", "hypertension", 
    "kidney_disease", "liver_disease", "lung_condition", "obesity"
    ), class = "factor"), chills = c(26L, 22L, 23L, 43L, 22L, 15L, 
    43L, 24L, 20L), cough = c(58L, 57L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 
    58L, 59L), diarrhoea = c(21L, 14L, 16L, 25L, 19L, 21L, 25L, 19L, 
    22L), fatigue = c(59L, 51L, 53L, 62L, 54L, 49L, 62L, 56L, 54L
    ), headache = c(44L, 30L, 34L, 44L, 39L, 33L, 48L, 43L, 42L), 
        loss_smell_taste = c(21L, 21L, 19L, 25L, 19L, 23L, 28L, 20L, 
        19L), muscle_ache = c(47L, 44L, 43L, 60L, 46L, 43L, 56L, 
        45L, 46L), nasal_congestion = c(34L, 25L, 32L, 36L, 33L, 
        33L, 46L, 38L, 34L), nausea_vomiting = c(11L, 10L, 9L, 18L, 
        7L, 12L, 28L, 13L, 9L), shortness_breath = c(61L, 36L, 32L, 
        53L, 35L, 50L, 44L, 50L, 37L), sore_throat = c(46L, 36L, 
        39L, 51L, 49L, 50L, 57L, 45L, 49L), sputum = c(47L, 34L, 
        41L, 50L, 39L, 41L, 47L, 46L, 43L), temperature = c(20L, 
        31L, 31L, 32L, 23L, 18L, 38L, 23L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L), groups = structure(list(Comorbidities = structure(1:9, .Label = c("asthma", 
    "diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", "hypertension", 
    "kidney_disease", "liver_disease", "lung_condition", "obesity"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the k-means clustering I have applied:

```
data_scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data_piv[2:14])) 
km_res <- kmeans(data_scaled, centers = 4, nstart = 25)
```

And tried to plot it :

```
fviz_cluster(km_res, data = data_piv)
```

And of course the picture above has been achieved with Comorbidities being transformed in an integer. Yet as I said, I dislike as it is not elegant. I want, instead of the numbers, to get the actual names of the factor variable. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
library(factoextra)
#Code
data_piv <- as.data.frame(data_piv)
data_piv$Comorbidities <- as.character(data_piv$Comorbidities)
rownames(data_piv) <- data_piv$Comorbidities
data_scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data_piv[2:14])) 
km_res <- kmeans(data_scaled, centers = 4, nstart = 25)
fviz_cluster(km_res, data = data_scaled)
```

[image]

Comment: would you please explain what rownames does? I will mark this as the answer tomorrow as it is late. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @GaB Explanation next -> It looks like `fviz_cluster()` takes as reference the rownames of data. This is just an index showing to which rows data belongs to. In your case, as no rownames was present, the function took the automatic index in all dataframe which goes to 1 to n. In order to get the names you want you have to replace that number by the labels you want. I hope that helps!